# Como colocar uma string no final de todas URLs via PHP (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, url, get

Estou utilizando o framework CodeIgniter para desenvolver um sistema. Porém na empresa onde estão usando, as páginas não estão atualizando direito, é como se ficasse o cache dá página inteira e só quando dou um F5 ele atualiza.

Por exemplo, tem uma tela onde exibe todos os usuário, se cadastro um novo usuário e volto para essa página ele não exibe o novo usuário, só quando dou um F5 é que ele atualiza e mostra o novo usuário.

Consegui resolver o problema colocando uma string aleatória no fim da URL como se fosse um GET, dessa forma o navegador entende que é uma nova página e carrega do zero.

O problema é que são muitas páginas, existe algum configuração no CodeIgniter ou uma função no PHP que coloque uma string no fim de todas as URLs ?

**Ficando assim:**
exemplo.com?FaYrSkuVu

Ou alguém sabe alguma outra forma de resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Será que o cache do CodeIgniter não está ativo? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html

Comment: Esse cadastro é via AJAX?

Comment: @RenatoTavares acho q não, por que só acontece nesse local, nos outros lugares que testei funciona normalmente. E nesse local acontece a mesma coisa em outros sites.

Comment: @PapaCharlie o cadastro não é feito via AJAX. O cadastro é feito via POST.

Comment: provavelmente seu servidor tem um delay de leitura, ou algum sistema de cache. Existe também a possibilidade do codeigniter estar fazendo cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para desativar cache do CodeIgniter você pode remover essa tag do seu projeto ou zerar o tempo de cache:

```
$this->output->cache(0);
```